# Response null después de llamada ajax al back

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot, httpservletresponse

Estoy haciendo una función para crear un excel sencillo mandando un listado hago todo el trabajo del back pero cuando intento leer el response (xhr) me dice que está vacío y es más el content type lo envío para excel al back, desde el back lo seteo otra vez y en el front con el ajax me lee application/html puede estar preconfigurado desde algún archivo js?

mi ajax

```
$.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify(delAdjust),
        contentType: "application/vnd.ms-excel",
        sendMethod: "POST",
        target: "exportar_registros",
        success: function(data, status, xhr) {
            if (data != null && data != "FAIL") {
                var b64Data = data;
                debugger;
                var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"); //Obtenemos el tipo de los datos
                var filename = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Disposition"); //Obtenemos el nombre del fichero a desgargar
                filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("=") + 1) || "download";
...
         }
    });
```

el xhr no está como lo que mando desde el back

```
@RequestMapping(value = "exportarRegistros", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    @Mantenimiento
    public void exportarRegistros(@RequestBody final RegistroDto registro,HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AccessDeniedException, IOException, AjusteException {

        List<AjusteDto> listadoAjustesFinal  = this.ajusteGenerateExcel.listadoAjustes(registro);
        HSSFWorkbook resultado = this.ajusteGenerateExcel.exportAdjust(listadoAjustesFinal);

        File file = File.createTempFile("ajustes-", ".xls");
        FileOutputStream report = new FileOutputStream( file.getPath() );

        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel;base64");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());

        resultado.write(report);
        resultado.close();
        report.close();

        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)file.length()];
        in.read(bytes);
        String encodedBase64 = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(bytes));
        response.getOutputStream().write(encodedBase64.getBytes());
        in.close();

    }
```

el problema no es si carga bien el excel coge bien los datos, eso lo miraré despues, el problema lo tengo en el front no me llega el response(xhr)

Comment: ¿Has probado a hacer un flush() o un close() sobre el outputstream?

Comment: no es esto? report.close();

Comment: Te sale algun mensaje en la consola del navegador (boton derecho inspect console) ? Y en la parte de network podes ver la llamada y en todo caso la respuesta?